# Power BI count null rows

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have two columns. Both have a general key INT value called TicketId, but one table has less TicketIds than another table. Both tables have different quantity of columns, so =EXCEPT() formula wouldn't fit.

For example, the current counting of rows looks like this:

| Dates | Tab1 | Tab2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08.11.2022 | 1058 | 950 |
| 09.11.2022 | 1058 | 1056 |
| 22.11.2022 | 2342 | 302 |

I am looking for a DAX measure forluma that will calculate TicketIds that exist in Tab1, but doesn't exist in Tab2. It should be not a formula like 1058 - 950 = 108. Because after there will be drillthrough to show all the TicketIds that were calculated (exist in Tab1 and doesn't exist in Tab2).

| Dates | Tab1 | Tab2 | Tabcross |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08.11.2022 | 1058 | 950 | 108 |
| 09.11.2022 | 1058 | 1056 | 2 |
| 22.11.2022 | 2342 | 302 | 2040 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a model like this:

[image: Modeling View]

and your datasets like this:

[image: Data]

Define your measures like this:

```
OnlyTable1 = COUNTROWS(VALUES(table1[TicketId]))
OnlyTable2 = COUNTROWS(VALUES(table2[TicketId]))
ID_Difference = COUNTROWS(EXCEPT(
                    VALUES(table1[TicketId]),
                    VALUES(table2[TicketId])
))
```

Then if we put it on a table visual:

[image: ViewWAY]

Comment: Everything worked, thank you sir!

Comment: You're welcome! Good to hear that It worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to apply EXCEPT() to your problem:

```
TabDiff =
EXCEPT (
    VALUES ( Tab1[TicketId] ),
    VALUES ( Tab2[TicketId] )
)
```

Note that this creates a calculated table.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it in a moment

Comment: It did it, but it calculated total of Tab1 vs total of Tab2. If I put this measure in a matrix vis, where presented graduation by dates, it will show the same one number row by row. Need to calculate this inside of each date presented in date graduation